# Обработчик Audio JavaScript HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, аудио, события

Здравствуйте.
Есть такой js-скрипт:

```
<script>
function start1() {
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById('f1').files[0]);
audio.autoplay = true;
}
function start2() {
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById('f2').files[0]);
audio.autoplay = true;
}
...
function stop() {
var audio = new Audio();
audio.stop();
}
</script>
```

и html код:

```
<body>
<input type="file" id="f1"></input>
<input type="file" id="f2"></input>
...
<button onmousedown="start1()" onmouseup="stop()">1</button>
<button onmousedown="start2()" onmouseup="stop()">2</button>
...
```

Как можно понять по скрипту он проигрывает звук из файла, который загрузит пользователь через форму для файлов.
Но возникают две проблемы:
1) необходимо, чтобы звук проигрывался только во время события нажатия на кнопку (onmousedown) и останавливался когда отпускают кнопку мыши (onmouseup).
Сейчас же звук проигрывает до конца не важно нажал ли ты кнопку мыши или отпустил ее (потому что нет проверки условия на это).
2) также необходимо создать упрощенный вариант скрипта, так как функций для обработки должно быть **16 штук**, но не вручную прописывать же каждую function.
Необходимо создать генерируемый скрипт, который будет обрабатывать N-количество id (start1, start2 и т.д и f1, f2 и т.д).

Помогите доработать код, можно также полностью код на jquery. это не критично.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ну не работает он потому, что вы в функции **stop()** создаете новый объект. Вообще если у вас несколько одинаковых сущностей, то стоит подумать об использовании массива:

```
var audios = []; // наш массив
// нужно его заполнить, как вариант функцией через цикл
function createAudio (file) {
   var audio = new Audio();
   audio.src = file.files[0];
   audios.push(audio); // добавляем в массив
}

// пропускаем по циклу
var fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='file']");
for(var i in  fileInputs ) {
   createAudio(fileInputs[i]);
}

// теперь наши функции управления
function playAudio(index) {
   audios[index].play();
}
function stopAudio(index) {
   audios[index].stop();
}
```

А вот html:

```
// нумерация с нуля идет, поэтому не перепутайте!
<button onmousedown="playAudio(0)" onmouseup="stopAudio(0)">1</button>
<button onmousedown="stopAudio(1)" onmouseup="stopAudio(1)">2</button>
```